# Soap Web Service structure

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm working on an integration project with a .net web service, which I am accessing with php soap.

It's been a bit of a challenge throughout, but I've managed to find the correct way to call things apart from this one method, which is for adding a product order line where the product has options.

Here is what a product's question and answer response looks like against the product record (limited below to 1 question, there are actually 3 against this product);

```
[GetOptionQuestionsResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [OptionQuestion] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [OptionQuestionID] => 7373
                        [Descriptor] => Scatter Fabric Front.
                        [OptionType] => Choice
                        [OptionQuantityType] => OneOnly
                        [OptionPriceType] => NotSet
                        [OptionChoices] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [OptionChoice] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [OptionID] => 17053
                                                [Value] => Pastiche Chocolate
                                                [SellingPrice] => 0
                                                [HasOptions] => 
                                            )[1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [OptionID] => 17054
                                                [Value] => Pastiche Sage
                                                [SellingPrice] => 0
                                                [HasOptions] => 
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [OptionID] => 17055
                                                [Value] => Pastiche Spruce
                                                [SellingPrice] => 0
                                                [HasOptions] => 
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [OptionID] => 17056
                                                [Value] => Stilnovo Paisley
                                                [SellingPrice] => 0
                                                [HasOptions] => 
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

Here is the method for adding a product with options from the wsdl, which is called AddOrderLineForBaseProduct. Plus the additional elements for adding an actual answer (OptionAnswerForChoice / OptionAnswerForFreetext);

```
<s:element name="AddOrderLineForBaseProduct">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="BaseProductID" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="optionAnswers" type="tns:ArrayOfOptionAnswer" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Quantity" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="BaseSellingPrice" type="s:decimal" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="VATID" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TakeFromStock" type="s:boolean" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LeadTime" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PromotionID" type="s:int" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:complexType name="ArrayOfOptionAnswer">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="OptionAnswer" nillable="true" type="tns:OptionAnswer" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="OptionAnswer">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="_optionType" type="tns:OptionQuestionType" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="_optionQuantityType" type="tns:OptionQuestionQuantityType" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="_optionPriceType" type="tns:OptionQuestionPriceType" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OptionQuestionID" type="s:int" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Quantity" type="s:decimal" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SellingPrice" type="s:decimal" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="OptionAnswerForFreeText">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="tns:OptionAnswer">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FreeText" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="OptionAnswerForChoice">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="tns:OptionAnswer">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OptionID" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OptionAnswers" type="tns:ArrayOfOptionAnswer" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
```

Here is the array I build in php to add the options, I'll just share the first 'OptionAnswer';

```
$optionsAnswers['OptionAnswer'][] = array(


    'OptionQuestionID' => 7373,
    '_optionType' => 'Choice',
    '_optionQuantityType' => 'OneOnly',
    '_optionPriceType' => 'NotSet',
    'Quantity' => 1,
    'SellingPrice' => '0',

    // TRYING TO ANSWER THE QUESTION HERE
    //'OptionID' => 17053,
    //'OptionAnswerForChoice' => array('OptionID' => 17053),
    //'OptionAnswer' => array('OptionAnswerForChoice' => array('OptionID' => 17053)),
    //'OptionChoices' => (object)array(
    //  'OptionID' => 17053,
    //  'SellingPrice' => '0'
    //),
    //'OptionChoiceID' => 17053,

    );
```

As you can see I've tried various angles on trying to set the actual answer ID for the question, but they are all ignored.

When I run the process;

```
//build order line array
$orderLine = array(
'BaseProductID' => $productId,
'optionAnswers' => $optionsAnswers,
'Quantity' => 1,
'BaseSellingPrice' => $linePrice,
'SellingPrice' => $linePrice,
'VATID' => 5,
'VATAmount' => $lineVat,
'TakeFromStock' => false,
'LeadTime' => $leadTime,
'PromotionID' => $promoId

);


try {
$addOrderLine = $client->__call('AddOrderLineForBaseProduct',array('parameters' => $orderLine));
} catch (Exception $e) {
print_r($e);
}
```

The feedback from the webservice is;

```
[detail] => stdClass Object
    (
        [NetWebServiceException] => Neither Choice nor FreeText has been specified. (at OptionAnswer position 1).
    )

)
```

Can anyone see how the OptionID should be added to the OptionQuestion array?

Many thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Makes it a little tougher looking at a partial wsdl but the type that your are giving your value should correspond to the type attribute specified in the wsdl. For example, where you have `'_optionType' => 'Choice',` the value for "Choice" should be a complex type of "OptionQuestionType" but you are just giving it a string. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback.  I should have added those bits, OptionQuestionType is a simpletype;

    <s:simpleType name="OptionQuestionType">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="NotSet" />
          <s:enumeration value="Choice" />
          <s:enumeration value="FreeText" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>

Comment: Ok that piece makes more sense then. Another thing I notice is that OptionAnswer has specified a sequence and OptionQuestionID is 4th in that sequence. You have it first in your array. Make sure your array is using the correct order.

Comment: Great shout, but unfortunately same response.   The web service is written .net - could there be a compatability issue with optionanswer not inheriting optionsnswerforchoice?